# Filter/Group GridDataControl Column by Referenced Display Name

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I have a view model with a list of portfolios and a list of portfolio owners. 
Portfolios is a view model that references the owner by the field `OwnerId`.

I want to have the grid display the owner's name rather than the Id, so I set the column style to `DropDownList`, providing the details to set up the reference between the two lists.

```
<syncfusion:GridDataControl ItemsSource="{Binding Portfolios}"
                            AutoPopulateColumns="false"
                            ShowGroupDropArea="True"
                            >
    <syncfusion:GridDataControl.VisibleColumns>
        <syncfusion:GridDataVisibleColumn MappingName="OwnerId" HeaderText="Collector" AllowFilter="True" IsReadOnly="True">
            <syncfusion:GridDataVisibleColumn.ColumnStyle>
                <syncfusion:GridDataColumnStyle CellTypeEnum="DropDownList"  DisplayMember="OwnerName" ValueMember="OwnerId" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ownersSource}" />
            </syncfusion:GridDataVisibleColumn.ColumnStyle>
        </syncfusion:GridDataVisibleColumn>
    </syncfusion:GridDataControl.VisibleColumns>
</syncfusion:GridDataControl>
```

My issue is, both the automatic filter and group by header display the `OwnerId` rather than the `OwnerName`, ignoring the column style I set.  How can I get those to display the `OwnerName` as well?